# Node.JS + WebSockets + Express: Download File

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Ok, so, yeah. I have the following `server.js` file with a web server + WebSocket implemented and, I was wondering, could I send file content through my WebSocket, and then using Express, create and send a download?

**Server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var server = app.listen(80);
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

app.use('/stick', express.static(__dirname + '/stick'));

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  console.log('websocket... on!');
});
```

I was thinking maybe doing something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var server = app.listen(80);
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

app.use('/stick', express.static(__dirname + '/stick'));

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  ws.on('download', function(data) {
    server.createRequest('foobar'); // I don't know if this even exists!
    //OR
    server.writeHeader(200, "foobar");
  });
  console.log('websocket... on!');
});
```

I know with PHP I could just set the headers and echo the content, can I do the same thing here?

Comment: Perhaps start with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/delivery

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I'm looking for, but, see I want to transfer a JSON file and I thought of using data: URIs but I don't want a HUGE URL.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear on what you are trying to do. If you simply need to transfer a JSON file using websockets, I don't see why delivery or a similar package wouldn't get the job done.

Comment: Because, I want to send the object using `JSON.stringify()` to my server. The server processes it, and returns another JSON file for the client to download.

Comment: For websockets, I like socket.io. You can stringify your object, emit it as the message and parse it back to JSON on the other side. If you can make a simple hello world websocket implementation, you should be able to do this. Just replace hello world with your stringified object.

Comment: Yes, but I need to send a JSON file to download with the data hidden (so you can't read it from the URL).

Comment: You can't send it the same way?

Comment: No, because there is no way to create a download in the browser.